# Telegram Logout Active Session : Account_GetAuthorizations return 0 hash for active session

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I Use Wtelegram Client
I Need Get All Active Session With This Code Ok
C# Code

`Account_Authorizations getsession = Task.Run(async () => await clienttelegram2.Account_GetAuthorizations()).Result;`

But I Want Get Session Hash Of My Active Session Return Zero :

`foreach (TL.Authorization item in getsession.authorizations) { if (item.api_id == XXXXXXX) { bool logoutok = Task.Run(async () => await clienttelegram2.Account_ResetAuthorization(item.hash)).Result; break; } }`

Please See Screen Shot of My Code
[image: Screen Shot of My Code]

Thx For Reading MY Problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current active session (see flags "**current**" on your screenshot) has a zero hash because it cannot be terminated in this way.

- `Auth_ResetAuthorizations()` is used to terminate all devices/sessions, except the current one
- `Account_ResetAuthorization(hash)` is used to terminate another specific device/session based on its hash
- `Auth_LogOut()` is used to terminate the current session

"Terminate" means that device/session is forced to logout from the current user account.

Comment: Thx problem solve with auth_logout() of WTelegram Client .